# Updating excel rows with data in the form of python dict_items

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which have value which needs to be updated to an excel sheet with corresponding column headers ,

```
new=[{"slno":"1","region":"2","customer":"3"}]
```

I am not sure about data types in python as I am a beginner,

All I want to do is update an excel sheet with the data from the above dict using a for loop. I always end up with a unordered data,

In the excel file there are column headers with the name exactly that of the Key of the dict so I was hoping to insert the respecting value in the excel column.

**Note: I was able to write it to excel using a for loop but dict was giving random numbers so the values were messed up when updated on sheet.**

```
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\\LoginLibrary\\test.xlsx')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('OE')
charcounter="A"
i=i
for key in g:
    sheet[charcounter+str(i)]=key
    charcounter = (chr(ord(charcounter[0]) + 1))
xfile.save('D:\\LoginLibrary\\test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the difficulties of dictionaries is that when you iterate over it as a loop, the keys can be in any order. However, something you can do is get the whole list of keys, then sort that list. For example:

```
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\\LoginLibrary\\test.xlsx')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('OE')
charcounter="A"
i=i
new = {"slno":"1","region":"2","customer":"3"} #The outer brackets made it a list, unneeded
print(sorted(new.keys())) #Prints out all the keys in alphabetical order
list_of_sorted_keys = sorted(new.keys())
for key in list_of_sorted_keys:
    sheet[charcounter+str(i)]=key
    charcounter = (chr(ord(charcounter[0]) + 1))
xfile.save('D:\\LoginLibrary\\test.xlsx')
```

Note: I don't know much about writing to excel, so I'm assuming that you have that part right. My additions just modify the dictionary so that it is organized.

If alphabetical order for the keys doesn't do your job, you can order by the values as well, although it's more difficult to get your keys from values because dictionaries aren't supposed to work that way.

Another way could be to just make the original data set as a list of tuples, as so:

```
new=[("slno","1"),("region","2"),("customer","3")]
```

That will keep all your data in order that you put it in the list, because lists are accessed by integer indices.

I hope one of these ideas meets your needs!